# Why is my Rails mountable engine not loading helper methods correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I've built a rails gem that mounts as an engine.

The engine is scoped to it's own namespace.

In the engine, there's an `MyEngine::ApplicationHelper` module which adds a bunch of view helper methods.

In my application layout, I refer to some of these methods.

When I first load any of the pages in development mode I get a `NoMethodError`, complaining that the method (defined in the gem's `ApplicationHelper`) doesn't exist.

Once I edit `ApplicationController` within my app, the problem corrects itself.

Something tells me this is down to the recent changes in Rails's auto-loading; I'm using Rails 3.2.2

I can't for the life of me work out why this isn't working properly though :/

Comment: I am facing same issue might be issue  because (Faster dev mode & routing) http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/20/rails-3-2-0-faster-dev-mode-routing-explain-queries-tagged-logger-store/. If u find solution kindly post it if i found solution i let u know.

Answer (score 42):

I think the Rails guides has the answer [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html#label-Isolated+engine%27s+helpers).

To include that particular helper from your Engine in your app:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper MyEngine::ApplicationHelper
end
```

To include all helpers from your Engine in your app:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper MyEngine::Engine.helpers
end
```

Comment: How can we access main app helpers into engine's view?

Comment: @AmitPatel (or anybody else that stumbles across this) - `helper Application::ApplicationHelper` worked for me to load the app's application helper in an engine controller (that I'd overridden). Others can be added in this way too.

Answer (score 7):

To load the engine's `GemName::ApplicationHelper` to be used in the views of the engine itself, I added following to the `engine.rb`:

```
module GemName
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace GemName

    initializer 'local_helper.action_controller' do
      ActiveSupport.on_load :action_controller do
        helper GemName::ApplicationHelper
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi @ryabrody I wish I could upvote you ten times. But here in 2022 This solution worked perfectly!!!

Comment: I'm getting: `Puma caught this error: undefined method \`helper' for ActionController::API:Class` when I do this :(