# Devise current_user not working in mountable engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-engines

Following [How To: Use devise inside a mountable engine](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-devise-inside-a-mountable-engine) and I can't get any of the Devise helper methods to show.

The Engine I'm using is `People`. (See my [full repo](https://github.com/woodall/lettuce/tree/add-users/apps/people))

```
module People
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    current_user
  end
end
```

Returns `undefined local variable or method 'current_user' for People::ApplicationController:Class`

I've tried the following

- `require 'devise'` at top of People::ApplicationController
- `require 'devise'` in host's application.rb
- Calling `main_app.current_user`
- Calling `People::User.current_user`
- Adding `helper People::Engine.helpers` (per [this SO suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10679313/935322))

### And, neither are sessions

Not sure if it's related, but when I `pry` into ApplicationController and type

```
# Pry Session
  session[:foo]
  => NameError: undefined local variable or method `session' for People::ApplicationController:Class
```

#### Additional Context, Devise is installed

I'm able to create Users.

```
# Pry Session
  People::User
  => People::User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is because you're attempting to access the instance method, `current_user`, in the class context and not the instance context. If you referred to the method inside an action in a controller, it should work.